# Radius to arc angle in conics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections

Attempted to reconcile below derived equation (3) approach with 2-body Newtonian   dynamic force equilibrium (4).They were compared in a numeric check, but no luck. Standard notation is used.

$$ \tan \psi =\frac{-2 \omega^2}{\alpha} \,; \,\tan \psi =\frac{-r^3\alpha}{\mu} ; $$

[image: ConicsRadius2Arcangle]

EDIT 1:

{Error in the above (4): $ \tan \psi $ should be perpendicular accln/radial accln.)

In this classic model at ends of major axis for $\psi$ to be $ \pi/2 ,\, \alpha $ should be infinite but that is never so.

What do I miss? Thanks for error trapping help.